# Imports in __init__.py and 'import as' statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I've run into a problem with having imports in `__init__.py` and using `import as` with absolute imports in modules of the package.

My project has a subpackage and in its `__init__.py` I "lift" one of the classes from a module to the subpackage level with `from import as` statement. The module imports other modules from that subpackage with absolute imports. I get this error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'subpkg'`.

## Example

**Structure**:

```
pkg/
├── __init__.py
├── subpkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── one.py
│   └── two_longname.py
└── tst.py
```

**pkg/**init**.py** is empty.

**pkg/subpkg/**init**.py**:

```
from pkg.subpkg.one import One
```

**pkg/subpkg/one.py**:

```
import pkg.subpkg.two_longname as two

class One(two.Two):
    pass
```

**pkg/subpkg/two_longname.py**:

```
class Two:
    pass
```

**pkg/tst.py**:

```
from pkg.subpkg import One

print(One)
```

**Output**:

```
$ python3.4 -m pkg.tst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/and/dev/test/python/imptest2/pkg/tst.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg.subpkg import One
  File "/home/and/dev/test/python/imptest2/pkg/subpkg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg.subpkg.one import One
  File "/home/and/dev/test/python/imptest2/pkg/subpkg/one.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg.subpkg.two_longname as two
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'subpkg'
```

### Workarounds

There are changes that make it work:

1. Empty `pkg/subpkg/__init__.py` and importing directly from `pkg.subpkg.one`.

   I don't consider this as an option because AFAIK "lifting" things to the package level is ok. Here is quote from [an article](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html):

   > One common thing to do in your `__init__.py` is to import selected
   > Classes, functions, etc into the package level so they can be
   > conveniently imported from the package.
2. Changing `import as` to `from import` in `one.py`:

   ```
    from pkg.subpkg import two_longname

    class One(two_longname.Two):
        pass
   ```

   The only con here is that I can't create a short alias for module. I got that idea from @begueradj's answer.

It is also possible to use a relative import in `one.py` to fix the problem. But I think it's just a variation of workaround #2.

## Questions

1. Can someone explain what is actually going on here? Why a combination of imports in `__init__.py` and usage of `import as` leads to such problems?
2. Are there any better workarounds?

---

## Original example

This is my original example. It's not very realistic but I'm not deleting it so @begueradj's answer still makes sense.

**pkg/**init**.py** is empty.

**pkg/subpkg/**init**.py**:

```
from pkg.subpkg.one import ONE
```

**pkg/subpkg/one.py**:

```
import pkg.subpkg.two
ONE = pkg.subpkg.two.TWO
```

**pkg/subpkg/two.py**:

```
TWO = 2
```

**pkg/tst.py**:

```
from pkg.subpkg import ONE
```

**Output**:

```
$ python3.4 -m pkg.tst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/and/dev/test/python/imptest/pkg/tst.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg.subpkg import ONE
  File "/home/and/dev/test/python/imptest/pkg/subpkg/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pkg.subpkg.one import ONE
  File "/home/and/dev/test/python/imptest/pkg/subpkg/one.py", line 6, in <module>
    ONE = pkg.subpkg.two.TWO
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'subpkg'
```

Initially I had this in **one.py**:

```
import pkg.subpkg.two as two
ONE = two.TWO
```

In that case I get error on import (just like in my original project which uses `import as` too).

Comment: I read your code again, case by case. I found that you missed one real fact: **tst.py** is under **pkg** itself, so each time you call `import pkg.subpkg.SOMETHING` or `from pkg.subpkg import SOMETHING` from WHEREVER you want, you will get the same error. I reedited my answer: I changed only the structure of your program, mainly **tst.py** is outside **pkg** (in fact, i run it this way since the first time i posted my answer below). If you WANT to keep **tst.py** inside **pkg** then remove `pgk` from all your calls like `import pkg.subpkg.SOMETHING`  and `from pkg.subpkg import SOMETHING`

Comment: `tst.py` is inside the package, that's the case. What do you mean by "remove `pkg` all your calls..."? Relative imports? I know that it would work with relative imports. The question is why it doesn't work the way it is.

Comment: I mean you need to run `import subpkg.SOMETHING` instead of `import pkg.subpkg.SOMETHING` and `from subpkg import SOMETHING`instead of `from pkg.subpkg import SOMETHING`. Why ? Well: you can not run your program with invalid paths. As simple as this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You incorrectly assume that one cannot have an alias with `from ... import`, as `from ... import ... as` has been there since Python 2.0. The `import ... as` is the obscure syntax that not many know about, but which you use by accident in your code.

[PEP 0221](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/) claims that the following 2 are "effectively" the same:

1. `import foo.bar.bazaar as baz`
2. `from foo.bar import bazaar as baz`

The statement is not quite true in **Python versions up to and including 3.6.x** as evidenced by the corner case you met, namely if the required modules already exist in `sys.modules` but are yet uninitialized. The `import ... as` requires that the module `foo.bar` is injected in `foo` namespace as the attribute `bar`, in addition to being in `sys.modules`, whereas the `from ... import ... as` looks for `foo.bar` in `sys.modules`.

(Do note also that `import foo.bar` only ensures that the module `foo.bar` is in `sys.modules` and accessible as `foo.bar`, but might not be fully initialized yet.)

Changing the code as follows did the trick for me:

```
# import pkg.subpkg.two_longname as two
from pkg.subpkg import two_longname as two
```

And code runs perfectly on both Python 2 and Python 3.

Also, in `one.py` you cannot do `from pkg import subpkg`, for the same reason.

---

To demonstrate this bug further, fix your `one.py` as above, and add the following code in `tst.py`:

```
import pkg
import pkg.subpkg.two_longname as two

del pkg.subpkg

from pkg.subpkg import two_longname as two
import pkg.subpkg.two_longname as two
```

Only the last line crashes, because `from ... import` consults the `sys.modules` for `pkg.subpkg` and finds it there, whereas `import ... as` consults `sys.modules` for `pkg` and tries to find `subpkg` as an attribute in the `pkg` module. As we just had deleted that attribute, the last line fails with `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'subpkg'`.

---

As the `import foo.bar as baz` syntax is a bit obscure and adds more corner cases, and I have rarely if ever seen it being used, I would recommend avoiding it completely and favouring `from .. import ... as`.

Comment: This is now fixed in Python 3.7, see issues [#23203](https://bugs.python.org/issue23203) and [#30024](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024).

Comment: it is probably worth noting that `import pkg.subpkg.two_longname` actually works but `import pkg.subpkg.two_longname as two` doesnt, in python < 3.7; so the problem is not caused by `import ...` vs `from ... import ...`; in python 3.7 both would work; issue 30024 covers this very well;

Answer (score 3):

Here is a theory on what's going on.

When you use the `as` reserved word, for instance:

```
import pkg.subpkg.two_longname as two
```

Python must to completely initialize and resolve all dependences that has to do with `pkg.subpkg`. But there is a problem, to completely load `subpkg` you need to completely load `one.py` as well right? wich at the same time imports `two_longname.py` using the `as` keyword ...  Can you see the recursion here? That's why at the moment of doing:

```
import pkg.subpkg.two_longname as two
```

you get an error claiming `subpkg` does not exist.

To perform a test, go to one.py and change it to this:

```
#import pkg.subpkg.two_longname as two
from pkg.subpkg import two_longname

#class One(two.Two):
class One(two_longname.Two):
    pass
```

I suppose this is all about performance, Python loads a module partially whenever is possible. And the `as` keyword is one of the exceptions. I don't know if there are others, but it would be interesting know about them.

Answer (score 3):

As the accepted answer states this is an issue with Python's behavior.

I've filed a bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue30024

The fix by Serhiy Storchaka was merged and expected in Python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

Your project structure regarding the way you call modules, must be like this:

```
pkg/
├── __init__.py
├── subpkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── one.py
│   └── two.py
tst.py
```

Define your **two.py** like this:

```
class TWO:
    def functionTwo(self):
        print("2")
```

Define your **one.py** like this :

```
from pkg.subpkg import two
class ONE:
    def functionOne(self):
        print("1")

        self.T=two.TWO()
        print("Calling TWO from ONE: ")
        self.T.functionTwo()
```

Define your **test.py** like this

```
from pkg.subpkg import one
class TEST:
    def functionTest(self):
        O=one.ONE()
        O.functionOne()
if __name__=='__main__':
    T=TEST()
    T.functionTest()
```

When you execute, you will get this:

```
1
Calling  TWO from  ONE:
2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My understanding is that moving the usage of imported stuff to functions helps because it lets python import everything first and then start using it. However it's not always possible to do. For example - importing a superclass. Probably I should base my example on that case to make it more real.

Comment: Also I've noticed you using `from pkg.subpkg import two` instead of `import pkg.subpkg.two as two`. This thing alone seems to make my original example work. I'll investigate it. Thank you!

Comment: I thought that using `__init__.py` to make classes, functions, etc available at package level is absolutely ok.