# `import as` in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How is this possible?

```
(Pdb) import brain.utils.mail
(Pdb) import brain.utils.mail as mail_utils
*** AttributeError: module 'brain.utils' has no attribute 'mail'
```

I always thought that `import a.c.d as m` is roughly equivalent to `m = sys.modules['a.c.d']`. Why `AttributeError`? Python 3.6

Comment: What is `brain.utils.mail`: a package, a module, a function/variable?

Comment: it's a module in package `brain.utils`. It cannot be a variable I think, `import brain.utils.mail` would fail.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24968941/831878

Comment: @RayToal yes, this is the answer! Thanks

Comment: I've created an issue for this: http://bugs.python.org/issue30024