# Python sub-sub-module: "import as" vs "import"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, attributeerror

I'm working in Python 2.7.

This is my folder structure. (`temp` is already added to this system path.)

```
temp
|
|--main.py
|
|--sub
   |
   |--__init__.py
   |
   |--sub2
      |
      |--__init__.py
      |
      |--square.py
```

The file contents are listed below.

```
main.py:

import sub.sub2 as sub2
sub2.run()
```

```
sub/__init__.py: empty
```

```
sub/sub2/__init__.py:

import sub.sub2.square as square
def run():
    square.square_it(3)
```

```
sub/sub2/square.py:

def square_it(x): return x**2
```

When I execute `main.py`, I receive the following error (ignore the line numbers):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sub.sub2 as sub2
  File "/home/gimlisonofgloin1/temp/sub/sub2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sub.sub2.square as square
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sub2'
```

I can fix this by changing the statement in which the error occurs to any of these statements (in the final three listed solutions, I have to change the function call appropriately, of course):

- `from sub.sub2 import square as square`;
- `from sub.sub2.square import square_it`;
- `from .square import square_it` (as pointed out kindly in user NeErAj KuMaR's answer); or
- `import sub.sub2.square`.

My question is: **why does the original line of code yield an error, even though it is semantically equivalent to the working ("fixed") lines of code (in particular, the 1st and 4th solutions listed)?**

In attempting to answer this question, I have stumbled across this bit of text from the [Python 2.0 Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html):

> To avoid confusion, you cannot import sub-modules 'as' a different local name. So 'import module as m' is legal, but 'import module.submod as s' is not. The latter should be written as 'from module import submod as s', see below.

This is consistent with the errors I'm receiving. However, this (seemingly important) little blurb is not present anywhere in the [Python 2.7 Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement). Is that little blurb from the Python 2.0 reference still applicable in Python 2.7? Or am I getting this error for a completely different reason that I'm not aware of?

Comment: you missed `__init__py` in temp directory.

Comment: Whoops. I meant to say that `temp` is already in the Python path, which means that ``temp`` doesn't need an `__init__.py` file. Edited question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you stumbled into a little known Python "gotcha" that seems to be [fixed in Python 3.7 Alpha 1 thanks to Serhiy Storchaka](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024). Check this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845671/import-as-in-python-3.

This was discussed in [Python Ideas](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2017-April/045405.html), but `import foo.bar as eggs` is not the same as `from foo import bar as eggs`. They generate inconsistent bytecodes.

> The root cause is the import cycle. I played around with dis and found the following (I suspect others have already found this but the thread was hard to follow for me initially):

```
>>> dis.dis('import a.b')
1         0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
          2 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
          4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (a.b)
          6 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
          8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
         10 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

> compared to

```
>>> dis.dis('import a.b as c')
1         0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
          2 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
          4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (a.b)
          6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (b)      <-- error here
          8 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
         10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
         12 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

> What this shows is that the implementation of "import a.b" and "import a.b as c" are different. The former calls **import**('a.b', ...) which returns the module 'a' and stores that in the variable 'a'. In the OP's case, because of the import cycle, while sys.modules['a.b'] exists, module 'a' does not yet have the attribute 'b'. That's the reason that in the latter example, the LOAD_ATTR opcode fails.

```
>>> dis("import sys.path as path")
1         0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
          3 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
          6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (sys.path)
          9 LOAD_ATTR                1 (path)
         12 STORE_NAME               1 (path)
         15 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
         18 RETURN_VALUE
```

> For "import sys.path as path", the given module name is "sys.path", and the "from list" entry on the stack is None. This fails before it even reaches the `LOAD_ATTR` line, since "sys.path" isn't an importable module. Changing LOAD_ATTR to IMPORT_FROM would thus have no effect on its behaviour.

```
>>> dis("from sys import path")
1         0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
          3 LOAD_CONST               1 (('path',))
          6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (sys)
          9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (path)
         12 STORE_NAME               1 (path)
         15 POP_TOP
         16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
         19 RETURN_VALUE
```

> For "from sys import path", the given module name is "sys", and the "from list" entry on the stack is a tuple containing the string "path". This works, since "sys" is importable *and* it has a "path" attribute.

I guess you have to wait for 3.7 or change your import.

Answer (score 0):

Replace code of sub2 `__init__.py` code as below

```
sub/sub2/__init__.py:

from .square import square_it
def run():
    square_it(3)
```

Comment: I am aware that this (an explicit relative import) can be done, although I have not listed it. My question, however, is _why_ the particular statement `import sub.sub2.square as square` causes an error. I will list this as another successful alternative in my question.

Comment: Check out this pull request: https://bugs.python.org/issue30024

Comment: @PauloScardine , thanks! That explained everything. The comments on the pull request link to a StackOverflow question/answer which is, I think, nearly-identical to mine. Should I answer my own slight variation on the question and link to that answer, or just mark my question as a duplicate?

Comment: Lets mark this as a dupe then...