# "import ... as .." trigger AttributeError

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I use "import as" like

```
import tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops as ass
```

I get "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'"

but code below like

```
import tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops
```

works fine

**env: python 3.6.3 + tensorflow 1.3.0**

Comment: `from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops as ass`

Comment: this works fine, but how "as" cause the problem as I described in the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate combination of TensorFlow's interface sealing (e.g. removing `tf.python` symbol visibility from `import tensorflow as tf`) and [Python import semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968941/6824418). The `import tensorflow... as` syntax will only access public TensorFlow symbols, while `from tensorflow... import ... as` can also access private symbols with no [API stability guarantees](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/version_compat).