# Are python circular imports an implementation detail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, documentation, python-import, circular-dependency

Is the behaviour of *circular imports* well-specified in Python, or is it just implementation-specific?

For example in cpython, importing a submodule causes the submodule to be assigned as an attribute of the parent module, *but not until after* the submodule finishes executing. Is this stated anywhere in the docs or PEPs?

More often then not, python circular imports just work (assisted by conventions like not executing any functions during import, and laying out the source code to define functions in the reverse of expected call order), but a consequence of the above behaviour is that you cannot refer by parent to a partially imported module. For example, if importing `package.submodule` causes an import of `othermodule`, then `othermodule` cannot do `import package.submodule as submod` but *can* do `from package import submodule as submod`. Is this explained/specified by the documentation? If not, is it likely to change?

In this case, the discrepancy is because `import package.submodule as submod` is implemented as a call to `__import__` (that returns `package`) followed by an attribute lookup (to retrieve `submodule` so that it can be assigned to `submod`). In contrast, `from package import submodule as submod` causes `__import__` to directly return `submodule` (which seems to work even if `submodule` is still only half-complete).  You could figure some of this out if you delve through the cpython bytecode (documented in the `dis` section of the standard library) and study the `__import__` semantics. However, since resolving circular imports is a common issue in python, it would be useful to find an official high-level summary of what to expect?

Example:

```py
mkdir package
touch package/__init__.py
cat > package/submodule.py << EOF
def f():
  print('OK')
import othermodule
othermodule.g()
def notyetdefined():
  pass
EOF
cat > othermodule.py << EOF
def g():
  try:
    import package.submodule as submod # this fails
  except AttributeError:
    print('FAIL')
  from package import submodule as submod # this works ok
  submod.f()
  #submod.notyetdefined() # this cannot be invoked
EOF
python -c 'import package.submodule'
```

Output in python 3.6.7:

```
FAIL
OK
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22187279/7389264) is related, but, while the answers do touch on the behavior of circular importing, they don't say anything about whether it is part of the specification or not. My own assumption, which I believe is supported by some of the answers to the other question, is that the well-defined behavior of imports in general leads to a consistent, even though it is not explicitly documented.

Comment: Also of note, this only prints "OK" in Python 3.7 and 3.8.

Answer (score 2):

From a little research, it sounds like the answer is that there is a bit of both specification and undocumented behavior involved, relating to how modules are initialized and how different forms of the `import` statement resolve (sub)modules. Overall, it looks like the behavior of circular imports *should* be fairly well-defined by the system, but the behavior you saw was "an implementation quirk."<sup>1</sup>

While I didn't investigate the rules of Python's import system in great detail, I was able to get to the bottom of the particular issue you observed.

To get there, I first noticed that, the behavior of your code changed in Python 3.7: it now only prints `OK`. This point from [the changelog for Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.7.html#other-language-changes) says why:

> Circular imports involving absolute imports with binding a submodule to a name are now supported. (Contributed by Serhiy Storchaka in [bpo-30024](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024).)

The discussion on the Python issue that led to the change contains some discussion of what was going on before, as well as a handful of links to earlier discussions of why the pre-3.7 behavior worked why it did. I found a few of the comments and links to be particular useful here:

The very first comment gives an explanation for the the behavior you observed ([this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968941/7389264) discusses how the same error occurs in a similar case):

> The background here is the change in http://bugs.python.org/issue17636 that allows IMPORT_FROM to fall back to sys.modules when written as "from a.b import c as m", while the plain LOAD_ATTR generated for "import a.b.c as m" fails.

Note that [bpo-17636](https://bugs.python.org/issue17636) motivated the support of "[c]ircular imports involving relative imports" [in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.5.html#other-language-changes).

More generally, for your answer, [this comment](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024#msg291400) (from Guido himself) states that the behavior of circular imports *is* defined:

> The semantics of imports in the case of cycles are somewhat complex but clearly defined and there are only a few rules to consider, and from these rules it is possible to reason out whether any particular case is valid or not.

Based on the fact that neither "circle," "cycle," nor any of the obvious variants thereof appear in [the documentation for the import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), I assume that the rules regarding cyclic imports, while consistent, are emergent properties of the system rather than explicit behaviors.

(Note that the documentation for the import system also doesn't mention the changes in 3.7, and doesn't mention anything about `import ... as ...` or `from ... import ...` at all. While [the documentation for the `import` *statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) does discuss the different forms of the statement, it doesn't discuss cycles either (and most of it hasn't been updated in [at least 3 years](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/8f4bbb5d627e07a5508099e84796cecaeb9e32ab/Doc/reference/simple_stmts.rst#L716)).)

---

There's also one small change coming in Python 3.8, though it does not appear to be in [the changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.8.html).

If you uncomment `submod.notyetdefined()` in `othermodule`, Python 3.6 and 3.7 both raise the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'package.submodule' has no attribute 'notyetdefined'

In Python 3.8.0b4, this more useful message is produced instead:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'package.submodule' has no attribute 'notyetdefined' (most likely due to a circular import)

This message appears to be the result of a [simple check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3e429dcc242e48fa4cbb1a91cf7c416c37b97b4e/Objects/moduleobject.c#L745) whether the current module is being initialized when a missing attribute was accessed; it's doesn't actually do anything relating to circular exports, except know that they are the most likely reason that an undefined attribute of a module might be accessed while it is being initialized.

---

<sup>1</sup> Ironically, that quote is from [this email](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-April/125121.html), which is given in the discussion for bpo-30024 as the rationale for the changes arising from bpo-17636—they fixed one case, but left another as it was, and that's what caused your error.

Comment: So Guido asserts that it is clearly defined, we're just not sure where? (Which few only rules is it?)

Comment: I suspect he meant it's clearly defined in the same same sense I did: the documentation doesn't say "circular imports work like this," but they do say what gets imported when, and by following those rules, you can figure out how cycles should resolve.

Comment: Does it say whether or not modules have attributes corresponding to partially-initialised submodules? (Is that the change for 3.8?)

Comment: It's not stated in the documentation, along with anything else about partially-initialized submodules, presumably because the use of partially-initialized modules is not intended. However, it is easy to write a test that shows that no such dummy attributes do not exist. This is also implied by some of the discussion on bpo-17636. As for the behavior in 3.8, I've updated my answer to say how that change works.