# Filled __init__ seems to block access to modules in same package

Tags: python, import, module, package, init

In a project one module `moduleA` requires access to module `moduleB` within the same sub-package `packageA` (which is in package `project`).
This access fails, when the `__init__.py` of sub-package `packageA` is filled with an `import .. as ..` statement, while the `__init__py` of package project is empty.

Why does a filled `__init__.py` (seemingly) block access from this (same package) modules - while PyCharm seems to still accept it from an autocomplete and highlighting perspective?
The thrown `AttributeError` suggests, that the `import .. as ..` statement makes the interpreter believe that the sub-package is an attribute, not an package – despite an existing `__init__.py`.

**File structure**

```
├── ProjectA
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── project
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── packageA
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   ├── moduleA.py
│   │   │   │   ├── moduleB.py
```

**Code sample 1**

```
# ProjectA / src / project / __init__.py
(empty)

# packageA / __init__.py
(empty)

# packageA / moduleA.py
import project.packageA.moduleB as dummy

class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

# packageA / moduleB.py
def method():
    pass
```

**Code execution 1**

```
# jupyter stated in 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\devenv\\'
# notebook located in 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\devenv\\dev\\'
import sys
sys.path
# output:
# ['C:\\src\\ProjectA',
#  'C:\\src\\ProjectA\\src',
#  'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\devenv\\dev',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\python36.zip',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\DLLs',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv',
#  '',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
#  'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
#  'C:\\Users\\username\\.ipython']

from project.packageA.moduleA import A, B
# no error(s)
```

**Code sample 2**

First alternative filling of `packageA / __init__.py`

```
# packageA / __init__.py
from .moduleA import A, B
import .moduleB as dummy
```

Second alternative filling of `packageA / __init__.py`

```
# packageA / __init__.py
from project.packageA.moduleA import A, B
import project.packageA.moduleB as dummy
```

**Code execution 2**

```
from project.packageA.moduleA import A, B
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-61a791f79421> in <module>
----> 1 import project.packageA.moduleA.moduleB

C:\src\ProjectA\src\project\packageA\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .moduleA import A, B
      2 from .moduleB import *

C:\src\ProjectA\src\project\packageA\moduleA.py in <module>
---> 1 import project.packageA.moduleB as dummy
     2 
     3 class A:

AttributeError: module 'project' has no attribute 'packageA'
```

## Solution

I've found the solution in [Stack Overflow: Imports in `__init__.py` and `import as` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968941/4186233)

Changing the import in `packageA / __init__.py` from `import .. as` to `from xx import .. as` did the trick:

```
# packageA / __init__.py
from project.packageA.moduleA import A, B
from project.packageA import moduleB as dummy
```

Can anyone help me to understand, why import xx as and from xx import xx as work differently, when it comes to sub-packages - specifically in this situation where the package's `__init__.py` is empty, but the sub-package's `__init__.py` is filled?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can actually not be described by any features of intended back-end mechanisms: the behavior doesn't match any of the documentation, e.g. [PEP 0221](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/). Thus the `import .. as ..` statement is nonfunctional.
This bug seems to have been fixed with [Python 3.7 (I've been running 3.69)](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024)