# Why does Python 2 try to get a module as a package attribute when using "import ... as ..."?

Tags: python, language-lawyer, python-import, python-3.7, circular-dependency

> **EDIT:** closely related to [Imports in __init__.py and `import as` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807434). That question deals with the behaviour of `import ... as ...` for up to Pyhon 3.6. The change in behaviour I'm describing below was introduced in Python 3.7, with the intention to fix the bug described in that other question. I'm more interested in where the change is documented (or where the two different behaviours, for Py2 up to Py3.6 vs Py3.7+, are respectively documented) rather than how exactly this behaviour arises (as I already mostly understand that as a result of experimenting in preparation for this question).

---

Consider the following directory structure:

```
.
└── package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    └── b.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty. The two modules `package.a` and `package.b` contain, respectively:

```py
# package.a
import sys

print('package.b' in sys.modules)
import package.b as b

spam = 'ham'
print("{} says b is {}".format(__name__, b))
```

```py
# package.b
import package.a

print("{} says package.a.spam is {}".format(__name__, repr(package.a.spam)))
```

With **Python 3.x** (specifically 3.8), When I run `python -c "from __future__ import print_function; import package.b"` from the root directory, I get

```
True
package.a says b is <module 'package.b' from 'C:\\[...]\\package\\b.py'>
package.b says package.a.spam is 'ham'
```

but with **Python 2.x** (specifically 2.7) I get

```
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "package\b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package.a
  File "package\a.py", line 4, in <module>
    import package.b as b
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'b'
```

The question is: what warrants this difference? Where is this change documented, e.g. the Python docs, a PEP or similar?

---

I get that `package.b` hasn't finished initialising when `package.a` is imported, so the module object for `package.b` hasn't yet been added as an attribute of the module object for `package`. But yet the module object itself exists (as it is added to `sys.modules`), so there shouldn't be any trouble binding the name `b` to that object, which is what Python 3 does I believe? Python 2 seems like it's not binding it directly to the module object, but rather trying to fetch it by getting an attribute named `'b'` from the module object for `package`.

As far as I can see, there is no such specification in the documentation.

[Import statement (Python 3.8)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

> If the requested module is retrieved successfully, it will be made available in the local namespace in one of three ways:
>
> - If the module name is followed by as, then the name following as is bound directly to the imported module.
>
> [...]

[Import statement (Python 2.7)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

> The first form of import statement binds the module name in the local namespace to the module object, and then goes on to import the next identifier, if any. If the module name is followed by as, the name following as is used as the local name for the module.

---

Notes:

- Using `from package import b` in `package/a.py` yields the same, only with a different error (i.e. `ImportError` instead of `AttributeError`). I suspect the `ImportError` is just wrapping the underlying `AttributeError`.
- Using `import package.b` in `package/a.py` doesn't give the `AttributeError` upon import in Py2. But, of course, referencing `package.b` later in the print call produces an `AttributeError` in both Py2 and Py3.

Comment: use please `from package import b` syntax

Comment: Are you aware that the import system was changed [at least in Python 3.4](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0451/)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, but nowhere did I see anything mentioning this change. Or rather, nowhere in the Py2 docs is there anything that would imply this behaviour. (Though sadly the Language Reference often leaves room for ambiguity or skips over details—it's more of a "Language Guide".) I know it's most likely not, but from what the docs say, one would think this is a bug in Py2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imports in \_\_init\_\_.py and \`import as\` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807434/imports-in-init-py-and-import-as-statement)

Comment: @DavisHerring Closely related, but not the same question. I was asking when that change got introduced, and where (if anywhere) that change is documented. In any case, the answers to that question mention the behaviour for up to Python 3.6 (which for `import ... as ...` is the same as for 2.7), whereas the change I'm interested was introduced in 3.7, as highlighted in the accepted answer below.

Comment: @Anakhand: A comment on the accepted answer there mentions the very same Python bug reports as the answer here (and as did my answer until I realized that the bug report linked to the duplicate question!).

Comment: @DavisHerring So we should close this as a duplicate of a question because said question has an answer on which a *comment* was posted containing part of the answer to this question? Seems kind of absurd to me

Comment: @Anakhand: The (accepted!) answer there says what version it was changed in, which is **already** really the answer to “Why does Python 2…?” because it means “The fix is too new to have been backported.”.  The comment merely cuts out the step of reading the release notes to find the bug number.  Would you be happier if someone edited the bug number into that answer?  (To be fair, the “For consistency” bit in the answer here is helpful and new.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216076/discussion-between-anakhand-and-davis-herring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
import package.submodule
```

and then try to access `package.submodule`, that access is an attribute lookup on the module object for `package`, and it will find whatever object is bound to the `submodule` attribute (or fail if that attribute is unset). For consistency,

```
import package.submodule as whatever
```

performs the same attribute lookup to find the object to bind to `whatever`.

This was [changed](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024) in Python 3.7 to fall back to a `sys.modules['package.submodule']` lookup if the attribute lookup fails. This change was made for consistency with a [previous change](https://bugs.python.org/issue17636) in Python 3.5 that made `from package import submodule` fall back to a `sys.modules` lookup, and *that* change was made to make relative imports more convenient.